# Macro to access source code of function at runtime

Tags: scala, reflection, macros, scala-macros

Using Scala macros I would like to get access to source code of function f.

Here is simplified example of my problem:

```
def logFImplementation(f: => Boolean) {
    val sourceCodeOfF: String = ... // <-- how to get source code of f??

    println("Scala source of f=" + sourceCodeOfF)
}
```

so for:

```
logFImplementation { val i = 5; List(1, 2, 3); true }
```

it should print:

```
Scala source of f=val i: Int = 5; immutable.this.List.apply[Int](1, 2, 3); true
```

(Right now I tested [Macro to access source code text at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972419/macro-to-access-source-code-text-at-runtime) and it works great for `{ val i = 5; List(1, 2, 3); true }.logValueImpl` but for `f.logValueImpl` it just prints `f`.)

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69412989/how-to-convert-scala-code-block-to-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *seriously* doubt that it is possible.

First, macros are *compile-time* thing. All they do is transform abstract syntax trees your program consists of. That's exactly the reason why you were able to do `{ val i = 5; List(1, 2, 3); true }.logValueImpl`: AST is right here, so there is no difficulty printing it as string. But macros just can't resolve runtime values, because there are *no* macros at runtime.

Second, there is absolutely no reason to believe that `f` is Scala code. I could call your function from Java like this (not sure that I got all names right, but the idea is still the same):

```
someObject.logFImplementation(new scala.Function0<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean apply() {
        // do some things in Java
    }
});
```

(and this is possible because internally call-by-name parameters are transformed into `scala.Function0` objects). What would you expect your function to print in this case?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, everything is correct, it is  Function0 and I agree with your answer completely. The question to you is: do you see any possible ways/techniques that will allow to grab Scala code from which Function0 was created by compiler? (and have access to this string at runtime)

Comment: No, there is no way. Scala does not save AST to the class files (and there is likely no space for it anyway), and you just can't reliably recover Scala code from byte code, and even if it did save AST, you just *couldn't* extract it from `f` using macros because macros work at compile time, and `f`s actual class (and hence implementation) is unknown util runtime.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev, I support your point of view, but I'd like to mention that in `scala.meta` (next generation of scala) there will be such a possibility (i.e. to carry AST to runtime), so there certainly *is* a place. Anyway, everything what you said is correct as for now.

Comment: Again thank you both for your answers. Maybe I can reformulate my question: how to create macro `logImplementation{ val i = 5; List(1, 2, 3); true }` that will print passed piece of code and return boolean value of evaluation? (If you want I can create next question at StackOverflow so community will not loose your advices.)

Comment: I posted other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418685/how-to-print-source-code-of-if-condition-in-then

Answer (score 5):

This is perhaps 'thread necromancy' as the question is quite old. I've had to grapple with this a bit.

```
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context
import scala.language.experimental.macros
object FunctionWrapper {

  implicit def apply[P, R](fn: P => R): FunctionWrapper[P, R] = macro apply_impl[P, R]

  def apply_impl[P: c.WeakTypeTag, R: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(fn: c.Expr[P => R]): 
                  c.Expr[FunctionWrapper[P, R]] = {
    import c.universe._
     c.Expr(q" new FunctionWrapper($fn, ${show(fn.tree))})")
  }
}
class FunctionWrapper[P, R](val fn: P => R, description: String) 
      extends Function1[P, R] {
  def apply(p: P) = fn(p)
  override def toString = description
}
```

An example of it in use (has to be in a separate compilation module) is:

```
 object FunctionWrapperUser {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val double = FunctionWrapper((i: Int) => i * 2)
    println(s"double to String is $double")
    println(double(4))
  }
}
```