# How to convert scala code block to string?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros

I need to implement a testing function which checks compile-time error information for the "splain" plugin, part of this function needs to convert a codeblock into a string, e.g.:

```
def convert(fn: => Unit): String

// for testing

val code = convert {
  object I extends Seq {}
}

assert(code == "object I extends Seq {}")
```

Is this possible using standard scala features? Thanks a lot for your advice.

This function will enable verifications of compile-time messages of complex code that needs to be indexed and refactored by IDE often

Comment: Which Scala version? Maybe you can achieve something with macros. Though I'm not sure you've given enough details about the context of why you need to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, it's possible.

Li Haoyi's macro [`Text`](https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/sourcecode/blob/master/sourcecode/src-2/sourcecode/Macros.scala#L133-L149) from [sourcecode](https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/sourcecode)

```
def text[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Compat.Context)(v: c.Expr[T]): c.Expr[sourcecode.Text[T]] = {
  import c.universe._
  val fileContent = new String(v.tree.pos.source.content)
  val start = v.tree.collect {
    case treeVal => treeVal.pos match {
      case NoPosition ⇒ Int.MaxValue
      case p ⇒ p.startOrPoint
    }
  }.min
  val g = c.asInstanceOf[reflect.macros.runtime.Context].global
  val parser = g.newUnitParser(fileContent.drop(start))
  parser.expr()
  val end = parser.in.lastOffset
  val txt = fileContent.slice(start, start + end)
  val tree = q"""${c.prefix}(${v.tree}, $txt)"""
  c.Expr[sourcecode.Text[T]](tree)
}
```

does almost what you want:

```
def convert[A](fn: => Text[A]): String = fn.source

convert(10 + 20 +
  30
)

//10 + 20 +
//  30
```

Unfortunately,

> if you have multiple statements in a `{}` block, `sourcecode.Text` will only capture the source code for the last expression that gets returned.

And since `{ object I extends Seq {} }` is actually `{ object I extends Seq {}; () }` the macro will not work in this case.

So let's write our own simple macro

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def convert(fn: => Any): String = macro convertImpl

def convertImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(fn: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._

  val pos = fn.pos
  val res = new String(pos.source.content).slice(pos.start, pos.end)

  Literal(Constant(res))
}
```

Usage:

```
trait Seq

convert {
  val i: Int = 1
  object I extends Seq {}
  10 + 20 + 30
  convert(1)
}

//{
//    val i: Int = 1
//    object I extends Seq {}
//    10 + 20 + 30
//    convert(1)
//  }
```

Notice that arguments of *def* macros are typechecked before macro expansion (so `convert { val i: Int = "a" }`, `convert { object I extends XXX }` without defined `XXX`, `convert { (; }` etc. will not compile).

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I got lucky it will be in the test code of the next version of scalac

Comment: It works, but with a caveat: The code must be parsed & typechecked. Or an error will be thrown before lihaoyi's macro can be invoked

Comment: @tribbloid In Scala all def macros are expanded after their arguments are typechecked.

Comment: @DmytroMitin, do you know a way to replace variables defined outside the convert method by their values? Like:

`val i = 5; convert(10 + i) // 10 + 5`

Comment: @MaxenceCramet Yes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132189 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767582 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60806283 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387459