# Scala 3 macro to list source code of file

Tags: scala, macros, code-snippets, scala-macros, scala-3

I'm developing a library and want to showcase some code in a small website. The code-snippets should be sourced directly from the same project, i.e. the code needs to be self-referencing.

I want to write a macro that, given a file or a classname returns a string with the file contents. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Suppose your macro is `inline def getContent(filePath: String): String = ${getContentImpl('className)}`. Is `filePath` a compile-time string (like in `getContent("path/to/file")`) or runtime string (like in `val str = "path/to/file"; getContent(str)`)?

Comment: Why do you want this to be a macro? Why can't it be an ordinary method?

Comment: The files don't exist at runtime. They are the the source of the running application.

Comment: I would also accept giving a classname or type as argument and returning the source of the class/object /trait or whatever implemented that type

Comment: *"The files don't exist at runtime."* Why? Are you deleting the sources after compilation?

Comment: Why not to run scala compiler at runtime and compile all necessary code snippets?

Comment: The files exist at runtime, but the application loses track of them. Running the compiler at runtime would cause so many problems I don't even know where to start.
Your answer below seems to be what I need - I'll return once I have the chance to test it out :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would also accept giving a classname or type as argument

Are you looking for such a macro?

```
import scala.quoted.*

inline def getContent[A]: String = ${getContentImpl[A]}

def getContentImpl[A: Type](using Quotes): Expr[String] =
  import quotes.reflect.*

     // for the source specifically of A
  // val str = TypeRepr.of[A].typeSymbol.tree.pos.sourceCode.getOrElse(
  //   report.errorAndAbort("no source code")
  // )

     // for the whole source file containing the definition of A
  val str = TypeRepr.of[A].typeSymbol.pos.getOrElse(
    report.errorAndAbort("no symbol position")
  ).sourceFile.content.getOrElse(
    report.errorAndAbort("no source-file content")
  )

  Expr(str)
```

```
// in a different file

getContent[A]

//import Macros.getContent
//
//object Main extends App {
//  class A:
//    def foo = 1
//
//  println(
//    getContent[A]
//  )
//}
```

[How to convert scala code block to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69412989/how-to-convert-scala-code-block-to-string) (Scala 2)

Comment: That's really good, thank you!

Comment: I have an issue -- sometimes it fails and the position is printed as "?", any ideas?

Comment: @Felix No. Weird. If the source is not available it shouldn't compile, not return `?`. Try to create reproduction

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hejfelix/24a59869231cf435a03370bd03d361ec
first time I run it in sbt, it works as intended and prints:

"
class Foo[F[_]] {

}
"

next time, if I insert a linebreak or any benign change, it prints an empty string with no error.

report.info reveals that the position is "?" and the sourceFile is "NoFile"

smells like a caching error.

Comment: Cleaning and recompiling seems to fix it, but then it quickly breaks again.

Comment: I have a repository to reproduce the issue here:
https://github.com/hejfelix/macro-repro

Comment: @Felix Clean compilation is a good practice while working with generated code. Behavior in Scala 2 is the same https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/344f2d1410b4f285bc95b8299f9096aa I suspect this is not a bug but how sbt + [zinc](https://github.com/sbt/zinc/) manage [incremental compilation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Understanding-Recompilation.html). Upon clean compilation sbt writes `compiling 3 Scala sources`, upon recompilation after modification of `SourceMacro` it writes `compiling 1 Scala source`, `compiling 1 Scala source`. I guess this makes impact on a position.

Comment: @Felix Why is clean compilation an issue for your use case?

Comment: I guess you're right. It is just annoying while debugging/developing. The final artefact comes from CI which currently does a clean compile so it should be OK. Thanks for looking into this, I have re-accepted 